# Python Help with Pygame and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, audio, multiprocessing, pygame

I'm using pygame to blit an image to screen, while it does the mainloop. I'm using multiprocessing for threads, but there seems to be a problem. Please don't chew me out over the weird wannabe xml comments, as I'm fairly new at this.

Here's my code.

```
#Import libraries
import pygame
import os, sys
import multiprocessing as threading
import time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1400,900), FULLSCREEN)
class loader:
    def sound(name):
        load = os.path.join("data", name)
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(load)
        return sound

    def song(name):
        load = os.path.join('data', name)
        song = pygame.mixer.Sound(load)
        return song

    def picture(name):
        load = os.path.join("data", name)
        image = pygame.image.load(load)
        image = image.convert()
        return image
    def movie(name):
        load = os.path.join("data", name + ".mpg")
        movie = pygame.movie.Movie(name)
        return movie











class data():
    class movies():
        #Turns out it's not supported D:
        pass
    class songs():
        theme = loader.song("theme.ogg")
    class sounds():
        fctune = loader.sound("fctune.wav")
    class pictures():
        fc = loader.picture("fc_opaque.tga")


#------------------------Logics-------------------------

def showlogo():
    screen.blit(data.pictures.fc, (0,0))
    data.sounds.fctune.play()
    time.sleep(30)



def startloops():
    logo = threading.Process(target=showlogo, args=())
    gameloop = threading.Process(target=mainloop, args=())
    logo.start()
    logo.join(None)
    gameloop.start()
    gameloop.join(None)

def mainloop():
    while 1:
        clock.tick(30)
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit(1)
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pass
            elif event.type is MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                pass
            #End of looper.


#-----------------------/Logics-------------------------



#----------------------Globals--------------------------

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
#----------------------/Globals-------------------------


if __name__ == "__main__": startloops()
```

What it does is it creates 2 pygame windows.. (one is supposed to show up when you call

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1400,900), FULLSCREEN)
```

So apparently it's calling that twice.
Hmm, multiprocessing seems to be the culprit. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I believe is happening. Basically, the `multiprocessing` module works by sending copies of everything that the `target` needs to a brand new interpreter; that's how it skirts the [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). But that means that side-effects (changes to global vars, changes to objects passed in but not returned) don't get propagated as expected. Here's a simple example:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> d = {'a':5, 'b':6}
>>> def alter_d():
...     d['a'] = 7
...     print d
... 
>>> p = multiprocessing(target=alter_d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> p = multiprocessing.Process(target=alter_d)
>>> p.start()
>>> {'a': 7, 'b': 6}

>>> d
{'a': 5, 'b': 6}
```

So as you can see, the version of `d` that has been passed to the new process has been altered. But the local version of `d` remains the same.

Now I don't know anything about the internals of pygame. But my guess is that when you create a new process using `logo = threading.Process(target=showlogo, args=())`, it makes a copy of `screen`. Then, either when that copy is made, or when `screen.blit(data.pictures.fc, (0,0))` is called inside the new process, a whole new screen gets generated.

Fortunately, the way you're using multiprocessing right now is completely pointless. `join` just halts the main process and waits for the subprocess to finish -- there's no concurrency whatsoever. Furthermore, I'd bet money that pygame provides whatever threading functionality you actually need -- I doubt you need multiprocessing at all. I'd suggest that you ditch it.